# SML - Recursive datatypes VS Polymorphic datatypes

Tags: sml

1. Can someone explain the difference between them?
2. Also, when trying out:

```
datatype exp = Const of real | Pair of exp * exp;

val my_exp_2 = Pair(Const(1.2),Pair(Const(9.0),Const(2.0)));
```

The interpreter gives:

```
val my_exp_2 = Pair (Const 1.2,Pair (Const #,Const #)) : exp
```

Why does the # symbol appear there?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the # as ... -- there are more nested expressions there, but the printer abbreviates them for readability. If this is SML/NJ, you can set e.g. `Control.Print.printDepth := 10` to adjust it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *recursive datatype* is a datatype, which uses itself in its definition.

An example of this could be:

```
datatype intlist = IntNil
                 | IntCons of int * intlist
```

Notice how `intlist` is used in the definition of the `IntCons` value constructor.

```
val ls = IntCons(5, IntCons(6, IntNil));
```

Notice how IncCons contains another list value in this example.

A *polymorphic datatype*  is a datatype, where one or more of the value constructors can contain a polymorphic value.

For instance, you could look at:

```
datatype 'a pair = Pair of 'a * 'a
```

Here, `'a` is a type variable, and as such the constructor can be used on values of any type. Example:

```
val pairInt = Pair(1, 5);
val pairStr = Pair("Hello", "Goodbye");
val pairChr = Pair(#"x", #"y");
```

These two things are often combined into *polymorphic recursive datatypes*, as is done for normal lists:

```
datatype 'a mylist = MyNil
                   | MyCons of 'a * 'a mylist;
```

This is both polymorphic and recursive, as can be seen in these examples:

```
val listInt = MyCons(5, MyCons(6, MyNil));
val listStr = MyCons("abc", MyCons("def", MyNil));
val listChr = MyCons(#"a", MyCons(#"b", MyNil));
```